# CQ5 creating an ordered list with a parsys

Tags: internet-explorer-8, aem

I have a component with a parsys that I would like to use to create an ordered list, using a Reference component. (i.e. user drags Reference comp. into parsys then selects a paragraph, creating item "1" in the list)

However, in IE8, the list that is created consists only of 1's; it does not increment.

Code is simple:

```
<ol>
  <cq:include path="numbered" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"/>            
</ol>
```

I have a feeling it has to do with how the code gets renedered:

```
<ol>
<div class="parsys numbered">
  <div class="disclosure-reference parbase section">
    <li>
      <div class="paragraph_element paragraph-element">
        <p>Item 1</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph-element section">
    <li>This is a new disclosure</li>
  </div>
</div>
</ol>
```

Since the `<li>` does not directly follow the `<ol>`, IE8 is not rendering the list correctly...

Is there any insight on how I can get around this issue? I've tried using `cq:cellName` set to blank, but that does not remove the 2 `<div>` tags following the `<ol>`

Answer (score 1):

For the component that you are using to drag and drop onto the parsys, you can use the property of cq:noDecoration = true. This prevents the element from being wrapped with a div tag and receiving the related class fields.

see this reference:
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html

If you are using the reference component. You may have to overlay or extend that component so that you can add this value.

Comment: The problem I just noticed this creates is that if I add this property to the parsys, it becomes disabled, not allowing me to drag anything into it.

Comment: found a relevant conversation http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1223235. It suggests using 

IncludeOptions opts = IncludeOptions.getOptions(request, true);
opts.setDecorationTagName("");

in an overridden parsys. If this was applied when not in edit mode it should duplicate the functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: @JEBailey  Setting the property of cq:noDecoration = true alone is not working for me.  I used <c:if test="${ requestScope['com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode']=='EDIT' || requestScope['com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode']=='DESIGN'}">
            <% componentContext.setDefaultDecorationTagName(""); %>
        </c:if>. It removed the div tags but I cannot edit the component on double click. How can I achieve explicit removal of div tags for a component?

Comment: @manojpt For your particular question, the test that you have is removing the decoration tag for EDIT and DESIGN mode. The decoration tags, the divs, are what gives you the ability to edit. You should leave them on EDIT and DESIGN mode and remove them for all others, so when you go to preview or publish it will display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, **remove** both the `<OL>` tag from the page that includes the parsys, and the `<LI>` tag from all parsys ITEM code.  Next, we tell CQ to use `<OL>` instead of `<div>` for the parsys group tag and and `<LI>` instead of `<div>` for the parsys item tag:

```
<%@page import="com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.IncludeOptions"%>
...
<%-- set the parsys decoration tagname to be an OL --%>
<% IncludeOptions.getOptions(request, true).setDecorationTagName("OL"); %>
<cq:include path="numbered" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"/>
```

In each parsys ITEM code folder, create a _cq_htmlTag.xml file (or you can [do the same in crxde](http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2013/04/modify_the_auto-generateddivs.html)):

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
cq:tagName="LI"/>
```